# how to make binary variable?

Tags: r

I have three Variables with the scale (0,1,2)
for Example;

| x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| NA | NA | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| NA | NA | NA |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to create another variable if variable x1 and/or X2 and/or x3 has 1 then x4 has to be 1, sample values for x4 are under

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| NA | NA | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I am using rstudio, i used if else function but I didn't get what I wanted.

can anyone please guide me what other ways I can have this variable.

I used following code

```
data$hope <- ifelse(data$x1 > 0 && data$x2 > 0 && data$x3 > 0,1,0)

data$hope <- ifelse(data$x1 > 0 && data$x2 > 0 && data$x3 > 0,1,0)
```

Comment: Remove the `&&` and replace with `&` i.e. `as.integer(data$x1 > 0 & data$x2 > 0 & data$x3 > 0)`

Comment: If it is binary for 'x4' then why some values are 2?

Comment: Based on your expected output, it looks like you want `max` i.e. `do.call(pmax, data)`

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly added the 2, that was NAs. but I used that code. somehow I still don't get what I want.

Comment: You need just `do.call(pmax, c(df1, na.rm = TRUE))#
[1]  1  0  1 NA  0`

Comment: @akrun many thanks, I've got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `pmax` if there are only binary columns in the dataset

```
df1$x4 <- do.call(pmax, c(df1, na.rm = TRUE))
```